# How to use --word_embeddings option of syntaxnet

Tags: tensorflow, syntaxnet

I am studying [Syntaxnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet) of Tensoflow.

Howerver, I'm confusing about the way to use `--word_embeddings` option. Could you show me a example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in read_ops.cc

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what syntaxnet is but here is how I use word embeddings in my sequence to sequence model.

Here I declare a variable which will store the embedding.  It is a matrix with rows equal to the number of words in the vocabulary (NWORDS) and each column is the size of the word vector for that word (WORD_VEC_SIZE).  It is randomly initialized and is a trainable parameter of the model.

```
  word_embedding = tf.get_variable('word_embedding', shape = (NWORDS, WORD_VEC_SIZE), initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 1,0))
```

The input to my model is a list of integers which represent the indexs of the words in the embedding.  It is of dimension BATCH_SIZE x TIMESTEPS.

```
source_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS), 'source_input')
```

Using the embedding and the input I can perform a lookup to convert the integer representations of the words into vectors.

```
y = tf.nn.embedding_lookup([word_embedding], source_input)
```

Now y has the shape (BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS, WORD_VEC_SIZE) and can be fed into the model for further processing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not exactly solution to my question. When I load pretrained word embeddings in syntaxnet, the error list below:raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [5,8] rhs shape= [31157,128]
         [[Node: embedding_matrix_0/init = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@embedding_matrix_0"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding_matrix_0, embedding_matrix_0/init/WordEmbeddingInitializer)]]